# Function to test if short numeric vector is a portion of long numeric vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to test if a short numeric vector is a portion of a longer numeric vector. For example, if `a = c(2, 3)` and `b = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1)`, then I'm trying to find / think of a function that would answer the question: is `a` a part of `b`? The output should be `TRUE`.

Alternatively, if `c = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1)` then the output of "is `a` a part of `c`?" should be `FALSE`.

`match()` doesn't do the job:

```
match(a, b)
```

returns

```
3  2
```

Nor does the `%in%` operator:

```
TRUE  TRUE
```

I know there are options for string matching but I'd prefer not to work around this issue by converting to strings...

Comment: Is there any reason you want to avoid converting to strings?

Comment: @nrussell - converting to strings can be quite slow at times compared to other solutions. But I'll absolutely reserve my judgement depending on what solutions people come up with.

Comment: @thelatemail That's true probably much more often than not, but occasionally I see a regex type function applied in an unconventional way (e.g. to numeric data) that performs surprisingly well overall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an attempt. I don't think it's super fast, but it's not super slow either:

```
a  = c(2,3)
b1 = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1)
b2 = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1)

ainb <- function(a,b) {
  any(apply( embed(b,length(a)), 1, function(x) all(rev(a)==x) ))
}
ainb(a,b1)
#[1] TRUE
ainb(a,b2)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Don't know why I got this answer accepted. All the others are more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my crack at it

```
valInLong <- function(val, long){
  n.long <- length(long)
  n.val <- length(val)
  # Find where in the longer vector the first
  # element of val is.  This is so we can vectorize later
  first <- which(long == val[1])
  # If the first element is too near the end we don't care
  # about it
  first <- first[first <= n.long - n.val + 1]
  # sequence from 0 to n.val - 1 used for grabbing subsequences
  se <- seq_along(val)-1
  # Look at all subsequences starting at 'first' that go
  # the length of val and do an elementwise comparison.
  # If any match in all positions then the subsequence is
  # the sequence of interest.
  any(sapply(first, function(x){all(long[x+se] == val)}))
}


long <- rpois(1000, 5)
a <- c(123421, 232, 23423) # probably not in long

valInLong(a, long)
a <- long[34:100]
valInLong(a, long)
```

Comment: Much, much quicker than my solution or `rollapply`

Comment: Fixed an issue if the 'first' was too near the end.  Probably slows it down a touch but it shouldn't be noticeable.

Answer (score 3):

You could always brute force it, if your vectors aren't going to be too long:

```
f <- function(a, b) {

    if(length(a)==0) return(TRUE)

    ix <- seq_along(b)

    for(i in seq_along(a)) {

        ix <- ix[which(a[i] == b[ix + i - 1])]
    }

    length(ix) > 0
}

f(a, b)
# [1] TRUE
f(a, c)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that OP writes "I'd prefer not to work around this issue by converting to strings...", and the comment by @thelatemail ("converting to strings can be quite slow at times compared to other solutions. But I'll absolutely reserve my judgement depending on what solutions people come up with.") I got a little bit curious to see how a string-based solution performed. Not too badly it seems.

Here I use `base` `grepl`, and the `stringi` equivalent `stri_detect_fixed`. They are fastest for the original (short) vectors. @Dason's solution is fastest for medium sized vectors, and the `for`-loop is fastest for 'long' vectors.

```
h1 <- function(val, long){
  grepl(pattern = paste0(val, collapse = ","), x = paste0(long, collapse = ","))
}

library(stringi)
h2 <- function(val, long){
  stri_detect_fixed(str = paste0(long, collapse = ","), pattern = paste0(val, collapse = ","))
}


a <- c(2, 3)
b <- c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1)
c <- c(1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1)

ainb(a, b) # thelatemail
valInLong(a, b) # dason
f(a, b) # pete
h1(a, b)
h2(a, b)

ainb(a, c)
valInLong(a, c)
f(a, c)
h1(a, c)
h2(a, c)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ainb(a, b),
               valInLong(a, b),
               f(a, b),
               h1(a, b),
               h2(a, b),
               times = 10)
# Unit: microseconds
#            expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval cld
#      ainb(a, b) 201.471 202.611 223.5567 211.7350 223.139 318.932    10   c
# valInLong(a, b)  67.664  76.407  90.2437  89.5215  99.215 129.245    10  b 
#         f(a, b)  36.873  42.195  54.2833  44.2860  55.879 129.246    10 a  
#        h1(a, b)  22.809  25.470  32.1595  27.1795  28.510  74.887    10 a  
#        h2(a, b)  20.147  22.048  31.7794  24.5190  26.609  96.174    10 a 


# vectors from @Dason's answer
val <- c(123421, 232, 23423)
long <- rpois(1000, 5)
microbenchmark(ainb(val, long),
               valInLong(val, long),
               f(val, long),
               h1(val, long),
               h2(val, long),
               times = 10)
# Unit: microseconds
#                 expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
#      ainb(val, long) 24673.332 24872.522 27732.2673 25685.4380 26962.877 45808.000    10   b
# valInLong(val, long)    50.558    55.880    68.5763    66.7135    81.349    91.233    10  a 
#         f(val, long)    69.945    80.588    89.1036    88.9515    99.215   115.561    10  a 
#        h1(val, long)   387.737   391.158   432.3644   421.5685   458.062   524.585    10  a 
#        h2(val, long)   337.559   342.120   378.1190   378.0425   382.035   458.442    10  a


# longer 'val' and 'long' vectors
val <- rpois(100, 5)
long <- rpois(10000, 5)
microbenchmark(ainb(val, long),
               valInLong(val, long),
               f(val, long),
               h1(val, long),
               h2(val, long),
               times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#      ainb(val, long) 298.967481 312.962860 322.350298 322.219875 329.194565 350.080246    10   b
# valInLong(val, long)   5.065280   5.237861   5.533719   5.532845   5.843414   5.921341    10  a 
#         f(val, long)   1.679050   1.717064   1.763288   1.747284   1.779786   1.907891    10  a 
#        h1(val, long)   3.648523   3.664869   3.751121   3.707634   3.753820   4.153720    10  a 
#        h2(val, long)   3.366463   3.444010   3.616591   3.478413   3.758761   4.309955    10  a
```

Comment: `h1` and `h2` have some overhead from dealing with strings, but they're implemented with efficient underlying algorithms. I don't think `f` uses the best algorithm for this problem, but it benefits from the vectorisation of `which`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on the clever answer by @thelatemail, as an infix operator:

```
`%w/in%` <- function(a, b)
{
    i <- length(a)
    x <- 1:(length(b)-(i-1))
    y <- x + (i-1)

    any(apply(cbind(x, y), 1, function(r) all(a == b[r[1]:r[2]])))
}
```

It sets up a set of indices to iterate through `b`, then passes over these to see if any if the selected subsets are all equal. Because it creates these indices before iterating, it may be inefficient in large vectors. Here it is in action.

```
> a <- c(2, 3)
> b <- c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1)
> c <- c(1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1)
> 
> a %w/in% b
[1] TRUE
> a %w/in% c
[1] FALSE
```

For what it's worth, this version seems to be significantly faster (after very brief testing):

```
> a <- c(2, 3, 1)
> b <- sample(1:4, 1000, replace=TRUE)
> a %w/in% b
[1] TRUE
> ainb(a, b)
[1] TRUE
> system.time(replicate(1000, a %w/in% b))
   user  system elapsed 
 11.175   0.000  11.187 
> system.time(replicate(1000, ainb(a, b)))
   user  system elapsed 
 19.930   0.000  19.949
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to exhaustively search the longer vector at all possible indices for a series of matches equal in length to the shorter vector. I doubt this way is efficient for very large problems and suspect that string conversion -- and also trying to simplify my own answer! -- would be worth investigating, but...

```
compareTuple <- function(v.lng, v.shrt, idx)
    {
    #idx is starting index of v.lng to begin comparison
    len = length(v.shrt)
    prod(v.lng[idx:(idx+len-1)] == v.shrt)
    }

containsTuple <- function(v.lng, v.shrt)
    {
    as.logical(sum(sapply(
                        FUN = function(x){prod(compareTuple(v.lng, v.shrt, x))}, 
                        X = 1:(length(v.lng)-length(v.shrt)+1)
                         )))
    }
```

should do the trick.  Here's the results:

```
a = c(2, 3); b = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1); c = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1)

> containsTuple(c,a)
[1] FALSE
> containsTuple(b,a)
[1] TRUE
```